# Angularjs directives vs scope specified behavior

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Still trying to wrap my head around how to do things properly in angular. So I have a directive like so

```
<div my-directive>
   <input type="button" value="Click" />
   <div id="someElementToRemove"></div>
</div>
```

I want to assign an onlick listener to the input button. This input button manipulates the DOM, removes some element within the directive template..so my question is where should I specify this behavior. I know controllers shouldn't have any DOM manipulation logic in it so would I create a directive just for this functionality?

For e.g.

...
    
   ...

my directive

```
app.directives.directive('removeElement', function() {
 //logic to remove element
}
```

I am just wondering if such a trivial functionality warrants a directive. Or should I assign a onclick handler in the directive via document.getElementById('button').addEventListener....

Ideally I would just like to assign an ng-click element to the button and create the logic in the controller like so. Which seems like the simplest method.

```
...
<input type="button" value="Click" ng-click="removeSomeElement()"/>
...

controller.js
...
$scope.removeSomeElement() = function() {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's probably a couple questions you should ask yourself in this situation.

- Do I want this bit of functionality to be reusable? If so, maybe it makes sense to move it over to a directive, especially if its doing DOM manipulation.
- Is the DOM manipulation fairly restricted to a certain DOM structure? If so then a reusable   directive won't help here, any maybe you should investigate an alternative to manipulating the dom.
- Do I actually need to manipulate the DOM? If it's such a trivial thing that it feels right to put it in the controller on an ng-click, well then you're probably right. Except you might not have to actually do any DOM manipulation. Could you instead manipulate the data in the controller and let some of the other angular directives that are built for DOM manipulation handle whatever the data says.

If you're just removing an element like you say you are this is the perfect place for ng-if.

Comment: Thanks Derek, in my case the functionality is a one time thing and not meant to be reusable. As far as manipulating the data in the controller..that would mean adding a $watch for that property in the directive, yes? Thanks again.

Comment: No problem. I'm not sure exactly how you're set up, but you shouldn't need a $watch call. You should be able to just have some scope Boolean that is equal to true. When you click the input button set that Boolean to false. Then on the element you wish to remove use the ng-if directive with the Boolean as the expression like: <element ng-if="myBoolean"></element>

Comment: Oh ok, I was not thinking about using ng-if. I know that it is a recent feature. I was wondering how this should be done prior to ng-if. I have enough info to do what I want..there just seems to be too many options. Thanks

Comment: Yeah, ng-if was added in 1.0.7 which is a stable release. If you want to see how they implemented ng-if take a look at https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngIf.js Though, there's some additional code in there specifically for ng-Animate support